# cookie is not working via curl or file get contents

Tags: php

I want to use a cookie from a requested page via curl. but it is not working properly

**example.com**

*index.php*

```
<?php 
    $cookie_jt = setcookie('jt','abcd',time()+3600,'/'); 
    var_dump($_COOKIE);
    //Result: array(['jt']=> string(4) 'abcd')
?>
```

**example.com**

*private.php*

```
<?php

    echo another_website('example.com/index.php');

    function another_website($api_url) {
        $connection_c = curl_init(); // initializing
        curl_setopt( $connection_c, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url ); // API URL to connect
        curl_setopt( $connection_c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 ); // return the result, do not print
        curl_setopt( $connection_c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20 );
        curl_setopt( $connection_c, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        $json_return = curl_exec( $connection_c ); // connect and get json data
        curl_close( $connection_c ); // close connection
        return $json_return; // decode and return
    }
?>
```

While I am using `private.php` at that time `var_dump($_COOKIE)` which I did in `index.php` website showing me `EMPTY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not accepting cookies on the curl request, you can use `curl_setopt` option parameter [CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) and [CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), i.e.:

```
function another_website($api_url) {
    $connection_c = curl_init(); // initializing
    curl_setopt( $connection_c, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url ); // API URL to connect
    curl_setopt( $connection_c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 ); // return the result, do not print
    curl_setopt( $connection_c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20 );
    curl_setopt( $connection_c, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt( $connection_c, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'sitex_cookies.txt'); // make sure the cookie file  is writeble by the webserver user
    curl_setopt( $connection_c, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'sitex_cookies.txt');
    $json_return = curl_exec( $connection_c ); // connect and get json data
    curl_close( $connection_c ); // close connection
    return $json_return; // decode and return
}
```

Comment: what should be in "sitex_cookies.txt"?? what content?

Comment: ok i used it. file is created. but var_dump($_COOKIE) still showing me EMTPY

Comment: **"sitex_cookies.txt"?? what content**- empty and writable, any name or file extension.

Comment: Yes the is writing in it. but when i do var_dump($_COOKIE); than it is showing me EMPTY

Comment: Enable php `display_errors` on both scripts in order to properly debug your code. Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);.`  right after `<?php` and re-run your scripts, does it output any errors?

Comment: $_SERVER is also not working while printing in `index.php`